# JSON Redirect fails for some IE users

Tags: php, json

I have a JSONP Script that loads a page which sends data to a remote webservice. Based on the response from this webservice this script then passes back a redirect URL. Now it works fine in IE, Chrome etc. However for some IE users it fails to redirect them and the page just 'sits' there doing nothing - as if the JSONP has stopped waiting for a response.

Ive logged all the variables, times, browsers etc. and I can see on average the script (submit.php) takes 22 seconds to run and returns what I would expect:

check_response({"status":"sold","message":null,"link":["https://remote.website.com/system/redirect.php?TMRMQT6q6kzz6ldJ8kN3xNor"]});

The JSONP call is below

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">    
submit_leads();

function submit_leads() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/wp-content/plugins/myform/submit.php",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        timeout: 300000,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        jsonp: check_response
    });
}

function check_response(data) {
    if (data.status == "sold") {
        console.log('We sold a lead!: ' + data.link);
        window.location.href = data.link;
    } else if (data.status == "nodata") {
        window.location.href = 'https://www.mysite.com/form';
    } else {
        window.location.href = 'http://www.redirect.com/product.php?id=c5609b53ca-a6fc65a0d4-37f8f83dc0-51082cac17&affsub=mobile_application';
    }
}
```

Im at a loss as to why, anyone any suggestions on what I can do or that I should be investigating?

Comment: 22 seconds to get the response? it's not really user friendly.

Comment: Does data.link contain special characters?

Comment: Try adding a error function to your jQuery.ajax that does something helpful in the case that things go wrong.